# There is an error regarding the Framer Motion useAnimation

Tags: javascript, framer-motion

Why is there an error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/279Ii.png)

```
import type { ComponentType } from "react"
import { createStore } from "https://framer.com/m/framer/store.js@^1.0.0"

var box1Control
export function box1(): Override {
    box1Control = useAnimation()
    box1Control.start({
        scale: 2,
    })
    return {
        animate: box1Control,
    }
}
```

USEAnimation test was in progress.
I want useAnimation to work.